# How to avoid magic strings and magic numbers in C++

Tags: c++

How do I avoid the use of magic strings and numbers in the code below:

```
void Trainee::setScores() {
  m_scores["C++"] = rand() % 100;
  m_scores["Java"] = rand() % 100;
  m_scores["Linux"] = rand() % 100;
  m_scores["QtQML"] = rand() % 100;
  m_scores["PSD"] = rand() % 100;
}
```

Comment: `constexpr const int modulus = 100;` ... unclear what is the problem...

Comment: Depending on the context and your class, I wouldn't necessarily call those string literals "magic". Besides, you can factor out `rand() % 100` into a custom (free) function and bind the `100`  to a variable which has a clear name. Besides, welcome to SO.

Comment: i have used string and number in above code which i want to avoid ...is there any alternate way

Comment: You could consider replacing the strings with enums to represent the discrete values (in this case, programming lanuages/OS)

Comment: "i have used string and number in above code which i want to avoid" -  avoiding magic numbers is not about avoiding numbers altogether, but about not repeating them. Do you actually want to get rid of the strings and numbers or do you want to avoid the duplication?

Comment: Your usage of strings does not qualify as "magic" - the strings are used in one place and in a way that is easy to understand.   If you want to avoid doing that, you need some alternative way of creating a map, such as reading the strings from a file, checking them, and using them to initialise your map.     To eliminate `100` as a magic value, create a named variable or constant with that value (i.e. you need to use the literal `100` once) and then use that named variable/constant where needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use constexpr variables in anonymous namespaces in *.cpp files (like static variables in C)

```
namespace
{
    constexpr std::string cpp { "C++" };
}

void Trainee::setScores()
{
  m_scores[cpp] = 
}
```

Comment: You also much want to have a *constexpr* variable to represent the top score `100`.

Answer (score 0):

If m_scores is an std::map, as it looks like, you could simply pass through all its content:

```
for( auto & score : m_scores ) {
  score = rand() % 100;
}
```

Also, you could add a function to set and save the modulus in a member variable of Trainee:

```
void Trainee::setScoresModulus( int modulus )
{
  m_modulus = modulus;
}
```

And then having:

```
void Trainee::setScores() {
  for( auto & score : m_scores ) {
    score = rand() % m_modulus;
  }
}
```

Edit: I miss read that the map was constructed in this function. Providing the list of all the scores names is one solution:

```
void Trainee::setScores( vector<string> const& names ) {
  m_scores.clear();
  for( auto const& name : names ) {
    m_scores[ name ] = rand() % m_modulus;
  }
}
```

Comment: this will just move the magic to different places. For the first snippet: who inserts the elements in the map? For the second: who calls the method and where does the parameter come from?

Comment: thanx bt what about the string part

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 the code can't have the information without any human intervention. It can be found in a config file (all possible names and the modulus) or given in any other way to the application and let this code generic and dynamic. 
It is still possible for the developer to move this magics in higher level functions that will call this class.